# c# "Bad Data" exception while decrypting - Using Base64 Encoding for transport

Tags: c#, android, encryption, cryptography

Ive been having some Crypto troubles cant see find what I've done wrong. I'm trying to encrypt an AESkey using RSA on Android and Decrypt it server side using C#, but keep getting a "Bad Data" exception.

I used Base64encoding to move the encrypted key from client to server and noticed that after moving it from the client(Android App) using a JSON POST request there were a number of "\u000a" in the key making the encrypted data length 941 which led to a "Data to large for decryption" when removed in brought the length to 920 which allowed for 80 8 byte iterations and got me to where I am now with the Bad Data problem.

I have checked that the key Length and Algorithm are correct and both are set for 2048 bit key and using PKCS1Padding.

"Bad Data" Exception
This exception will be thrown in the following scenarios.

a) The RSA private key used for decryption does not match with the RSA public key that is used for encryption.

b) The binary data passed in to Decrypt() method is incorrect. This could happen if the application code made assumptions about the length of encrypted data or the data passed in does not match the exact bytes that is returned from Encrypt() method.

I get the public key on android by pulling it from the server with a GET which returns RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXMLString(false); And use the same keystore for the private key so cant see it being 1.

And as far as I know the c# decrypter Isn't making any assumptions about the size of the encrypted data. Possibly my setting block size to 8 but thats after i knew the size of the encrypted AESkey.

I've been looking around for a solution and couldn't find one so would be grateful for any assistance. Apologies if I'm being stupid and missed something simple but I have my blinkers on if I am and just cant see it.

Java Encryption

```
private byte[] encryptRSA(byte [] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
        //instance of singleton PublicKey
        AppPublicKey currKey = AppPublicKey.getInstance();
        Log.d("ENCRYPT.MOD: ", currKey.getModBytes().toString());

        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(1,currKey.getModBytes()), new BigInteger(1,currKey.getExpBytes()));
        KeyFactory keyFactory =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        Log.d("RSAENCRYPTION: ",Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, 1));
        return cipherData;

 }
```

C# Decrypt

```
public string DecryptString(string inputString, int dwKeySize)
    {
        // TODO: Add Proper Exception Handlers
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = "real_Keystore";

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider
                                 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwKeySize,cp);

        int base64BlockSize = 8;               
        int iterations = inputString.Length / base64BlockSize;


        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(
                 inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));

            //Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
            arrayList.AddRange(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(
                                encryptedBytes, false));
        }
        return Encoding.UTF32.GetString(arrayList.ToArray(
                                  Type.GetType("System.Byte")) as byte[]);
    }
```

Comment: "_I get the public key on android by pulling it from the server with a GET._" And you are using TLS (https) for this, right? In which case you already have a secure communication channel and don't need this extra cryptography at all.

Comment: No im not using htts even though its probably alot easier, the final implementation may very well use Https. However, I really want to get this encryption/decryption working, its been bugging me for a while now and hate not being able to fix it.

Comment: If you don't use TLS for fetching the public key, all this cryptography is useless, because it's vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack. TLS solves this with signed certificates. There is some discussion about the issue here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx If you don't care about MITM vulnerabilities, you could just use Diffie–Hellman, which is a lot simpler than RSA.

Comment: Wow... i cant believe i missed that. I was running the Public key is Public so its fine mentality -_- .....  MITM hadn't even crossed my mind. Looks like TLS is the way to go for sure and that's what ill definatly use now for the actually implementation. Thanks for the input. I would still love to figure out why my solution isnt working though, for possible future use and just so i dont pull my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to feed a few bytes at a time to the RSA operation.

Furthermore it seems unlikely that the code performs the right amount of base 64 iterations (as you defined `NO_PADDING` for base 64 in your android, using `1` instead of the constant). Normally the output of RSA encryption won't be a multiple of 3 bytes, so you are at least one block off the mark.

You may want to take a closer look at the API functions you are using and take some time to study RSA examples on .NET. Normally RSA is only used to encrypt small amounts of data (such as symmetric data encryption keys) so you should be able to decode all of the base64 data in one go.

Please test your input and output in a debugger. Encryption/decryption problems normally require that the exact input and output of the encryption/decryption algorithms are compared .

Comment: Please let me know if this solves your issue. Forgot to welcome you to...welcome to Stackoverflow :)